# Requiring  references

Tags: mapping-class-groups, gt.geometric-topology

Assume $V$ be a genus larger than 1 handlebody, $S=\partial_{+} V$.

Denote $N$ be the normal closure of $MCG(V)$ in $MCG(S)$.

Is there any material related to the quotient group $MCG(S)/N$ ?
Thanks!

Comment: @l.Mosher:sorry I have it edited.

Comment: @Lee: He probably means normal closure. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal closure of $MCG(V)$ in $MCG(S)$ is all of $MCG(S)$. To see why, we know that $MCG(S)$ is generated by Dehn twists, so it suffices to prove that each Dehn twist is in the normal closure. Consider the Dehn twist $\tau_c$ about an essential simple closed curve $c$. There exists a homeomorphism $f : S \to S$ such that $c' = f(c)$ bounds a properly embedded disc $D \subset V$, and $\tau_{c'}$ extends to a twist about the disc $D$, so $\tau_c = f^{-1} \circ \tau_{c'} \circ f$ is in the normal closure of $MCG(V)$. To find this homeomorphism, observe that the there is one $MCG(S)$-orbit of nonseparating curves, and for each partition $genus(S)=m+n$ there is one $MCG(S)$ orbit of separating curves whose complements have genus $m,n$. Each such orbit clearly has a representative bounding a disc in $V$.

Comment: @L.Mosher: Assign $MCG(S)$ a clay graph $G$. Obviously there is a 

subgraph $G^{*}$ with vertices corresponding to $MCG(V)$. Is there a 

vertex in $G$ which is arbitrarily far from $G^{*}$ ?

Comment: @yanqing: I don't know what a clay graph is.

Comment: Cayley graph.  And the answer to your question is "Yes."  Said another way, the inclusion of $MCG(V)$ into $MCG(S)$ is not "coarsely dense."  I don't know a slick proof of this.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $MCG(V)$ has infinite index in $MCG(S)$. For any subgroup of any finitely generated group $G$, if the subgroup is coarsely dense then it has finite index in $G$. There might be a very slick proof somewhere, but there is a pretty quick proof of a more general result in my paper with Sageev and Whyte "Quasi-actions on trees I", which says that two subgroups of $G$ at finite Hausdorff distance from each other are commensurable in $G$. 

Comment: @Lee: This is very simple: If $|G:H|=\infty$ then $H\backslash G$ is infinite, so $X=H\backslash \Gamma_G$ has infinite diameter, where $\Gamma_G$ is a Cayley graph of $G$. Thus, you have geodesic paths $p_i\subset  X$ of arbitrary large length. Lifting these paths to $\Gamma_G$ proves failure of coarse denseness of $H$ in $G$. The same proof gives you the reverse implication.  

Comment: Which type is a vertex far from $G^{*}$? Is it possible that that vertex in G represents a reducible or periodic element in MCG(S)?

Comment: @Yanqing: Your latest question is not very well formed --- vertices in Cayley graphs do not have "types" because the group acts transitively on the vertex set. There might be a good question in there, but at this stage I suggest that you read more about the relation between MCG(S) and MCG(V) in paper by H. Masur, "Measured foliations and handlebodies".